# Respond.js not working

Tags: theming

Ive made sure my CSS files are being aggregated but respond.js isnt working.

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/cc/

Ive tried both the module (currently enabled) and also using the Zen themes built in option to use respond.js.

Ive added this for debugging, so when media queries are working the page is blank for desktop sized displays.

```
@media all and (min-width: 720px) {
  body {
    display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 'Debug info' turned on in my coumpas.app. Disabling this made it work.